# How to fill a Django form with an API response?

Tags: django, api, django-forms

I need to create a form of persons, where the camp Name must receive an API response. I created the formulary e rendered the api response in template, but I can´t put it in my formulary, in order to save in my Models camp Name. So, I just want to save my API respone inside my forms and in my database.

**Views**

```
def cadastro(request):
    url = 'https://gerador-nomes.herokuapp.com/nome/aleatorio'
    api = requests.get(url)
    nome_api = ' '.join(api.json())
    
    form = PessoaForm()
    form.nome = api
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = PessoaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data('nome')
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form': form, 'api': nome_api}
    return render(request, 'base/pessoa_form.html', context)
```

**pessoa_form.html**

```
<body>


    <form action="" method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}

        <input type="submit" name="Cadastrar">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Forms**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from . models import Pessoa


class PessoaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pessoa
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Models**

```
from django.db import models


class Pessoa(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    lastname= models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    age= models.IntegerField(null=True)
    birthday_date= models.DateField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    nickname= models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['nome', 'sobrenome']
```

I have tried some things of my head but nothing actually worked, like try to access the variable Name in my forms inside my template and inside my views.

Answer (score 0):

[English]
Well, by judging by the variable names you've chosen, I guess you're brazilian, so I'll post the answer in portuguese as well.
I don't know if this is the best practice, but you could just append the api response as a new field in the `request.POST`, for instance:

[Portuguese Translation]
Pelos nomes que tu usou, imagino que sejas BR então vou botar a resposta em Português também além do inglês.
Não sei se é o método que segue as melhores práticas, mas você poderia simplesmente adicionar a resposta da API como um campo novo no teu `request.POST`, por exemplo:

```py
def cadastro(request):
    url = 'https://gerador-nomes.herokuapp.com/nome/aleatorio'
    api = requests.get(url)
    nome_api = ' '.join(api.json())
    
    form = PessoaForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        updated_request = request.POST.copy()
        updated_request.update({'name': nome_api})
        form = PessoaForm(updated_request)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form': form, 'api': nome_api}
    return render(request, 'base/pessoa_form.html', context)
```

Comment: I'm actually BR too kkkkk, thank you man!